# Comparing Character value vs Character Array value

Tags: java

Having a bit of an issue with comparing a char value with a char value inside of an array. All I want to do currently is check if the `char = array[index]`. However upon doing this I can't get anything to NOT equal true. Everything comes back as if it is equal.

```
final Character[] answerKey = new Character[] {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
        int sLength = s.length();

        for (int i=0; i < sLength; i++)
        {
            Character j = new Character(s.charAt(i));
            for (int k=0; k < answerKey.length; k++)
            {
                if (answerKey[k].equals(j));
                {
                    System.out.println(answerKey[k] + "j=" + j);
                }
            }
        }
```

Everything gets printed out in the message even though my test case was "ab10".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic mistake of putting a semicolon at the end of the line.

```
         if (answerKey[k].equals(j));
         //                         ^ oops
         {
```

It's easy to avoid this. Put the brace in the correct place.

```
         if (answerKey[k].equals(j)) {
         //    a ; would be obvious ^ here
```

I once spent a day or two trying to work out why my embedded program was playing terrible quality audio. I though it was too slow (back of envelope calculations should have disabused me of that notion). After that, I always added braces (and in the correct place).

Comment: `The classic mistake` - that's why it is a dupe ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat It isn't obvious what to search for if you don't know what the problem is.

Comment: It shouldn't be a dupe.  Should be closed as "caused by a typo".  We surely don't want every possible typo turning up as a Stack Overflow question (or two).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It's fair to ask the question if you don't know what the answer is. And also there's a bit more information to give in the answer.

Comment: `java if always true`

Comment: @ScaryWombat OP thought the issue was with `equals`, not the `if`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Well if so, the OP will accept your answer.

Comment: @ScaryWombat That's never guaranteed, but they have done so in this instance. Somebody has given me a downvote, which seems a bit harsh given that it solves the OP's problem and shows how following conventions would have prevented the issue from arising.